# How to turn a pi into a router?

Tags: routing, isc-dhcpd

How do you use a raspberry pi as a router for a local network (LAN)?

Changed `/etc/network/interfaces` into

```
interfaces="eth0"
```

I installed `isc-dhcp-server` and configured it like so

```
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 604800;

authoritative;

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 {
        range 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.254;
        option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
        option routers 10.0.0.1;
}
```

the pi is connected to a switch that is also connected to another computer
when i reboot the computer no ip address is assigned to the other computer

this is what the log file at `/var/log/dhcp-server.log`

```
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[719]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.2-P1
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[719]: Copyright 2004-2021 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[719]: All rights reserved.
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[719]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.2-P1
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Copyright 2004-2021 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: All rights reserved.
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
May 28 20:54:43 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Server starting service.
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1184]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.2-P1
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1184]: Copyright 2004-2021 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1184]: All rights reserved.
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1184]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1190]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.2-P1
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1190]: Copyright 2004-2021 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1190]: All rights reserved.
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1190]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1190]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
May 28 21:10:30 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[1190]: Server starting service.
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[718]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.2-P1
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[718]: Copyright 2004-2021 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[718]: All rights reserved.
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[718]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.2-P1
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Copyright 2004-2021 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: All rights reserved.
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
May 28 21:11:22 kali-raspberry-pi dhcpd[734]: Server starting service.
```

Comment: Does it run?  Does it log anything?

Comment: a router between which? Can you explain what you want to achieve? This is a bit confusing, as your first sentence asks to convert a single device into a network – and devices and networks aren't the same thing, just as houses and cities aren't the same thing.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I updated the question and add the logs

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want to use the pi as a router setting up a dhcp server and using a switch connected to the pi to make a local network not connected to the internet

Comment: You're using Kali Linux for this, as your log tells us. That's a distro *especially* not meant for easy networking, having disabled-and-crippled-by-default network is the whole Kali thing. Please use **any** other Linux distro. There's even dedicated Linux distros for the RPi to be used as router! You're actively using the worst possible tool for the job.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what do you mean by disabled-and-crippled-by-default can you elaborate how kali is bad for this job what exactly is bad about kali in this project

Comment: Kali is highly specialized tool for pentesting. For that reason, by default it disables network interfaces, services and automatisms that are very useful in other use cases. See: [Should I use Kali?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) by the Kali Linux people.

Comment: @ilkkachu 3+ and 4 have Wi-Fi

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, d'oh, yes of course that would also work. (does it show that I like having cables around?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you're setting up a router, but it doesn't seem to have connectivity to more than one network segment. On the other hand, your code examples are about setting up a DHCP server.

A router's primary purpose is to *route traffic* between one network segment and another; it may have a DHCP server as an add-on function, or it may not.

Although a home router usually includes a simple DHCP server, a DHCP server does not make a system a router. In enterprise-grade set-ups, it is common to have multiple routers between different network segments, and perhaps one central fault-tolerant pair of DHCP servers. Even with most home routers, you can disable the DHCP server function and provide your own DHCP server if you want a more configurable DHCP service in your network.

A system running a DHCP server won't generally gets its own IP address from its own DHCP server; you'll need to set up a static IP address (e.g. 10.0.0.1) first. The DHCP server won't set up any local interfaces for you, and trying to have both a DHCP server and DHCP client operating on the same interface is likely to lead into nothing but a headache.

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` syntax does not look correct to me. Assuming Kali for RasPi uses the same syntax as generic Debian, you should write something like this:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Note, since you did not mention any connection to the outside world, the `gateway` line is intentionally omitted here.

Also, note that Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS favors configuring network interfaces via `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` instead of using `/etc/network/interfaces`. If your Kali for RasPi does that too, you might want to first disable `dhcpcd` to ensure it won't conflict with plain-Debian-style set-up you seem to be trying to achieve.

Once you have a network interface with a static IP address up and running, you can start thinking about configuring the DHCP server.

I'm afraid your `subnet` configuration for `isc-dhcp-server` has some errors in it.

First, you should exclude the DHCP server's own IP address (and any other systems that will have a statically configured IP) from the `range` clause.

Second, your subnet declaration disagrees with itself. If the broadcast address is supposed to be 10.0.0.255, then the `netmask` cannot be 255.0.0.0 but should be 255.255.255.0. And if you are just using one /24 block off the 10.0.0.0 ... 10.255.255.255 (also known as 10.0.0.0/8) private address range, your subnet declaration should also include a subnet mask DHCP option for the DHCP clients:

```
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
```

With these corrections, you should be able to make your RasPi a **DHCP server** for your LAN.

---

To make your RasPi a **router**, you would first need a second network segment of some kind: a second physical network interface, a VLAN, a smartphone with Internet tethering enabled, or perhaps a dedicated USB WWAN dongle.

On a system with multiple network interfaces, you should configure a *default gateway* only for the network interface that has connection to the internet. (Having multiple parallel internet connections goes into territory of *advanced routing*; you should get the simple case working first before even trying that.)

Once you have two or more network interfaces configured and connected to separate network segments, you only need to run

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and you will have a minimal *router*. (To make it persistent, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`.)

To make it actually useful, you might have to set up some `FORWARD` rules with `iptables` or the newer `nftables`, and possibly some `POSTROUTING` rules using `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE` targets if you want your router to provide internet access for your 10.x.x.x network segment.

If you are routing between two private network segments, this configuration will allow the RasPi to route traffic from the other network segment to your 10.0.0.0 ... 10.0.0.255 segment, and have the systems in that segment successfully answer to traffic inbound from that other segment.

But unless you do SNAT/MASQUERADE, then the systems in that other segment will also need to know that your system is a router for the 10.0.0.0/24 network segment, i.e. those systems will need an entry in their routing table, telling them that the 10.0.0.0 ... 10.0.0.255 segment is reachable using the IP address of your RasPi's other-network interface as a gateway.

The systems in the 10.0.0.0 ... 10.0.0.255 segment will already know that your RasPi is a router, thanks to the `option routers 10.0.0.1;` line in your DHCP server configuration.